# PHP7 CurlFile not exists, i already put the \

Tags: php

```
$postdata = array(
                    'method'    => 'post',
                    'key'       => $apikey,
                    'file'      => new \CurlFile($filename,'image/jpg'),
                    'phrase'        => $is_phrase,
                    'regsense'      => $is_regsense,
                    'numeric'       => $is_numeric,
                    'min_len'       => $min_len,
                    'max_len'       => $max_len,
                            'is_russian'    => $is_russian
                );
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,             "http://$domain/in.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,     1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,             60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,                true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,         $postdata);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The result response is:

Uncaught Error: Class 'CurlFile' not found in ...

Im running on PHP7.

So why?

Comment: I am guessing you don't have the mods for curl installed properly in PHP. Look in phpinfo(). Basically the script is unable to find the defination of CurlFile

Comment: Yeah. I have installed but forgot enabled in the php.ini. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl plugin should be properly installed. The same can be verified using `phpinfo()`